# Return view doesn't take variable in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Maybe is silly question but I have this in my Controller which is showing the form for image upload and after form is submitted should return me to another view.

On this another view I have passing variable with all images but still I've got

> Undefined variable: images

So this is what I have in my Controller

```
// Display all Images
public function images()
{
    $images = Images::paginate(3);
    return view('images', compact('images'));
}

// Display image upload form
public function imageCreate()
{
    return view('create');
}

// Submit and store image
public function imageStore( Request $request )
{
    $image = new Images([
      'caption' => $request['caption'],
      'name' => $request['caption'],
      'path' => 'uploads/noimage.png',
      'hits' => 1,
      'added_on' => '2017-08-08 9:00:00'
    ]);

    $image->save();
    return view('images', compact('images'));
}
```

And this in my view `images.blade.php`

```
@foreach($images as $image)

   <a href="{{ URL::to('image/'.$image->slug) }}"><img class="thumbnail block" src="{{ '../'.$image->path }}"></a>

@endforeach
```

So, why variable is undefined if I posting it in the return view statement?

Update: dd($image) in the view return

```
Images {#234 ▼
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #table: "images"
  +timestamps: false
  +fillable: array:6 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: true
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "caption" => "dasdsadsad"
    "name" => "dasdsadsad"
    "path" => "uploads/noimage.png"
    "hits" => 1
    "added_on" => "2017-08-08 9:00:00"
    "slug" => "dasdsadsad-7"
    "id" => 144
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

Update 2: routes

```
Route::get('images', 'HomeController@images'); 
Route::get('create',['as'=>'create','uses'=>'HomeController@imageCreate']); 
Route::post('create',['as'=>'store','uses'=>'HomeController@imageStore']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error int this line

```
return view('images', compact('images'));
```

your variable name is `$image` and you pass `$images`

replace above line with this

```
return view('images', compact('image'));
```

---

```
public function imageStore( Request $request )
{
    $image = new Images([
      'caption' => $request['caption'],
      'name' => $request['caption'],
      'path' => 'uploads/noimage.png',
      'hits' => 1,
      'added_on' => '2017-08-08 9:00:00'
    ]);
    $imagePath='uploads/noimage.png';
    $image->save();
    return view('images')->with('image',$imagePath);
}
```

you get path like this

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('image/'.$image->slug) }}">
 <img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Already tried this but I've got the error mentioned in comments under the other answer.

Comment: @Ivan i have update my answer.. try this don't work then i will give another idea

Comment: did you changed `compact('images')` to `compact('image')`?

Comment: Yes, I did changed it.

Comment: ok now you try this `{{dd($image[0])}}` or `{{dd($image[0]->path)}}` in view

Comment: Frist one return `null` second one return `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: i have update my answer... if you need only path then try this .. and if you need more data about image then tell me i will update my answer

Comment: I don't understand why this is needed? The idea is after image successfully uploaded to redirect me to image.blade which then should display all images from database.

Comment: after upload and save image then you should retrieve data from database(all images) and send to view

Comment: Okay, I've got result from `{{dd($image[0])}}` which is `"u"` but `{{dd($image[0]->path)}}` return `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: the final solution is you send me complete image view code and controller code.. i will fix your code...

Comment: They are in my question. Those are complete files.

Comment: if you get "u" then problem is solved.. i have mention in my answer `<img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">`

Comment: I've added also routes. No, when I remove remove the `dd` and leave it like this `<img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">` I've got `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: `<img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">` replace this line with this `<img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">`

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: bjadooon@gmail.com.. send me complete images.blade.php file code

Comment: It is in the question

Comment: Whole code is in the question. Controller + View + Routes.

Comment: ok. remove foreach loop and simple write `<a href="{{ URL::to('image/'.$image->slug) }}">
 <img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">
</a>`

Comment: But I need the loop. I want all images. Tried also without loop - `Trying to get property of non-object
`

Comment: you pass only one image data from the controller.. why you not understand... if you need all images data then you first retrieve from database and then pass to view

Comment: i have some changes in <img> tag.. please read carefully.. `<img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}">`

Comment: 1 minute.. `<a href=""> <img class="thumbnail block" src="{{url('/'.$image)}}"> </a>` try this

Comment: this is another error ... i have remove slug in <a> tag... because you not mention slug in controller..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146644/discussion-between-ivan-and-jadoon).

Answer (score 2):

The issue is here:

```
compact('images'));
```

but your variable is `$image`. So change it to:

```
compact('image'));
```

and try again. And also change the `foreach()` variable name like:

```
@foreach($image as $img)
...
$img->slug
$img->path
```

Explanation:

The variable that contains the data is `$image` and the one you are passing from controller is `compact('images'))`. An extra `s` is there.

[passing-data-from-controller-to-views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: But I have `@foreach($images as $image)` which take `images`

Comment: So what?, the variable that contains the data is `$image` and the one you are passing from controller is `compact('images'))`. An extra `s` is there in variable name

Comment: Wait a sec. When `imageStore` is performed and return view to `images()` doesn't it `images()` pass the `$images` variable?

Comment: If I change to `$images = new Images([` I've got `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: With compact you have to pass the same text as of variable name.

Comment: Yes, I've made the changes and thats what I've got `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Still same error `Trying to get property of non-object` inside the loop here: `<a href=""><img class="thumbnail block" src="{{ '../'.$img->path }}"></a>`

Comment: Access them like: $img->slug
$img->path

Comment: I've updated my question with `dd($image)` in the view. It seems that is there but still same error. You can see in above comment that I'm accessing it as you said - `src="{{ '../'.$img->path }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel assumes when you use the compact function that the variable you are passing is named the same as the variable you are passing in the route. For instance:

`route::get('/customer/{customer_id}', 'CustomerController@show');`

Therefore in your controller when returning data with your view you need to do something like:

`return view('customer', ['customer_name' => $customer->name]);`

Then you should be able to reference it in your view like:

`{{$customer_name}}`

Comment: Jeffery Way explains it well in this tutorial https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/5